# How do I add a border to the TextButton.icon?

Tags: flutter, flutter-text-button

[image: Screenshot]

I'm having issues with creating border around my TextButton.icon button. Could someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

I've managed to change the color of the text and icon but I just can't seem to change th icon button itself. I've tried a Container but it limits me to padding and all other sorts of wrapping that I have to apply.

Comment: Have you tried using [shape](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration/shape.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('ABC'),
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
  ),
),
```

That how it work. You need to use shape inside style.